Measured gain 10x higher than calculated gain - common source amplifier
I have a pretty basic common-source amplifier, using a 2n7000 nmos transistor. Gate bias is set with two resistors to give Vgg = 4.83V. Rd = 555.7Ohm and Rs = 218.8Ohm. There is a bypass capacitor across Rs, input capacitor between the gate and an ac source, and output capacitor before a 10MOhm load resistor. All capacitors are 1.2uF. Vdd is set to 13.25V

My problem is, if I calculate the expected voltage gain using Av = -(gmRd)/(1+gmRs), I expect a gain of around 2. However, when I measure the voltage gain it is over 20, and when I model the circuit in LTSpice, it is also over 20. What am I missing? It is driving me crazy - almost certainly something simple... The load resistor value is high enough that I can consider this to be the open-circuit gain. If I measure the transconductance using the transfer characteristics of the circuit (from the simulation), I obtain gm= -0.04... but to get a gain of 20, I need gm = -0.004. Grrrrr!

The feedback resistor Rs is active for DC (and very small frequencies) only. This is due to the parallel capacitor Cs.

I told you it would be something simple! :) So I shoudl be using Av = -gmRd, since Rs is bypassed. Ha. Thank you!

It will depend on frequency you are using to measure the gain.

@LvW can you turn your comment into an answer?

You could assume a constant voltage drop for VGS of 1.4 volts, giving you a voltage with an offset.  Then measure the complex impedance of Rs in parallel with Cs and calculate the current in the FET.  Multiply this by Rd to get you pretty close to the gain and phase at one specific sinusoidal frequency.   However, this is a case when the best approach is to do just what you have done - a spice program will give a more accurate result.

@littleWoodster I get gm about 0.0325 so a gain of about 18, using spice params and the DC quiescent point. Vgs = 2 V, Vth = 1.6 V. ID about 13 mA, so gm = 13 mA / (2 V - 1.6 V).
